# check message sent successfully from UIActivityViewController Swiftui

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to count the absolute frequency of sharing events (weather temp) when the app goes into the background (after sent mail or sms, share text)
i would like to use dictionary
◦ Key (number of days relative to Today, Tomorrow = 1, Day after Tomorrow = 2, etc.)
◦ Value: Number of times this day has already been shared.
print thsi dictionary in console.

I don't understand the status of the application, I don't know where I have the moment when I can add +1 to the dictionary, because the weather message has been sent

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isSharePresented: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var dictionary = [0: 0,1:0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //
            ForEach(0..<8) { index in
                HStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text("\(String(format: "%.1f",
                                daily.temperature2MMin[index])) °C ").padding(10)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(String(format: "%.1f",
                                daily.temperature2MMax[index])) °C ").padding(10)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.isSharePresented = true
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isSharePresented, onDismiss: {
                        print("Dismiss")
                    }, content: {
                        ActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Weather Forecast \nDay: \(daily.time[index]), \n Min temp: \(daily.temperature2MMin[index]), \n Max temp: \(daily.temperature2MMax[index])"])
//
                        self.dictionary[index]! += 1
                        print(dictionary)
                    })
                    
                }.padding(.horizontal, 20)
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            WeatherService().getDate { (results) in
                self.results = results
                print("Api Done")
            }
    }
}


struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}







struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var activityItems: [Any]
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        print("load sheet")
        return controller
    }
    
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {
    print("done sheet")
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a public iCloud database to put these values and then you can check either with an app or with web browser. This way it can be shared with no user interaction. Do not forget to include why you do this in confidentiality information.